# R create a data.frame by adding lines, one each time

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to populate a data.frame (or something like it) line by line (one record each time).My problems:

1. The data is not always present, and I don't want to lose the columns because they failed to have one instance of data. I want to set NA in this place.
2. New columns can appear in the middle of process and others can be no more available.

What I'm trying to do is construct a data.frame with one row and insert vectors.

Example:

```
ddf <- data.frame("1", "2", "3", "4", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(ddf) <- c("A","B","C","D")
View(ddf)
data_vector1 <- c("11","22","44")
names(data_vector1) <- c("A","B","D")
data_vector2 <- c("111","222","555")
names(data_vector2) <- c("A","B","E")

#What I want:
#     A    B    C    D     E  
#     1    2    3    4    NA
#    11   22   NA   44    NA
#   111  222   NA   NA   555

#Still now
samecols <- intersect(colnames(ddf),names(data_vector1))
ddf <- rbind(ddf, data_vector1[samecols])

#I'm getting:
#A  B  C  D
#1  2  3  4
#11 22 44 11
```

Comment: Do the rows depend on each other at all?

Comment: No, the answer from akrum did just what i was expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can place the datasets in a `list`, convert to `data.frame` and use `rbindlist` with `fill=TRUE`

```
library(data.table)
lst <- lapply(list(ddf, data_vector1, data_vector2), as.data.frame.list)
rbindlist(lst, fill=TRUE)
#     A   B  C  D   E
#1:   1   2  3  4  NA
#2:  11  22 NA 44  NA
#3: 111 222 NA NA 555
```

---

Or use `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(lst)
```

Comment: Trying to install data.table now.